# Mail not sent from Sql Server 2005 Stored procedure from batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, batch-file

I am facing a strange issue with a batch file as given below.
I have a .bat file created which calls a stored procedure as given below

```
sqlcmd -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[ABC]" -S "XYZ\INST5,1450" -U %USERNAME% -P %PASSWORD%  -d %DBName%
```

This command works fine. This SP will successfully send a mail to some users which is expected behavior.

But if I replace the variables used in the above command with actual values like this

```
sqlcmd -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[ABC]" -S "XYZ\INST5,1450" -U ABC -P LMN  -d DATABASE
```

and run the batch file,then i get a mail queue message and the mails are never send.

Now if I again run the same batch file then the mail gets send. To cut long story short, mails are send only after running the .bat file twice.

There is absolutely no issues with the SP as it currently fully tested and working successfully in production environment where it is scheduled as SQL job.

Kindly suggest why this .bat file fails the first time if the variables are replaced with actual values

Comment: Check your SQL Server's Error Logs for any relevant messages.